# "Failed to save undefined: null: Source" salesforce lightning controller erroe

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I just started with Salesforce Lightning and was doing trailheads. I wrote a component, when I try to save it gives me an error : Failed to save undefined: null: Source

Below is the Component code:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name = "item" type ="Camping_Item__c" required="true"/>
    <ui:OutputText value="{v.item.Name}" />
    <ui:OutputCurrency value="{v.item.Price__c}" />
    <ui:OutputText value="{v.item.Quantity__c}" />
    <ui:OutputCheckbox value="{v.item.Packed__c}" type="toggle}"/>

</aura:component>
```

Comment: May not be the cause of your problem, but the checkbox line should be `<ui:OutputCheckbox value="{! v.item.Packed__c }" type="toggle"/>` and other '!' are missing too.

Comment: I tried doing that.. just updated the ques.. was not working

Comment: Add some '!' characters too. `{!` starts an expression and `}` ends an expression.

Comment: Failed to save undefined: The attribute "type" was not found on the COMPONENT markup://ui:outputCheckbox: Source

Comment: @Ashutosh Arora, If you are following Trailheads, you should probably take some time to review the module before completing the challenges. they are pretty straightforward, and code snippets are usually provided, So you should not be having these errors.  Don't try to rush through them for the badges and points, Trailheads are in place to help you grasp the basics, which you clearly seem to be missing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP does not seem to be reading the trailhead modules carefully or putting effort in reviewing them in order to complete the challenge presented.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be as follows .  '!' are missing too.

```
===============
<aura:component > 
<aura:attribute name = "item" type ="Camping_Item__c" required="true" 
  /> 
<ui:OutputText value="{!v.item.Name}" />
<ui:OutputCheckbox value="{!v.item.Packed__c}" /> 
<ui:OutputText value="{!v.item.Quantity__c}" /> 
 <ui:OutputCurrency value="{!v.item.Price__c}" /> 
</aura:component>
===========================
```

Also ui:outputCheckbox does not have "type" attribute.
Please check the following link.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_outputCheckbox.htm